# Adding actions to UILocalNotification in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

I have an app that sends push notifications to the user.

I want to add to every notification 2 buttons (actions), I think it's called `Rich Notifications`.

I didn't find enough information on how to do it, so I would really appreciate if someone could guide me here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a notification category and the category will have notification actions. Those actions will define what the buttons say and what gets passed to your app when the user chooses one.

Comment: Do I need any additional framework in addition to the UILocalNotification class? And how can I create a category and actions? Thanks!

Comment: You need to import the `UserNotifications` framework. See the docs here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter

Comment: I've already read that. But I can't understand how to add an action to my `UILocalNotification` (and schedule it to NOW).

Comment: Use the init method of `UNNotificationAction` to create one for each button. Then add those to the category in its init. You can make the local notification fire now by passing `nil` to the trigger.

Answer (score -1):

Googling the keyword you provide return many results. Why don't you pick one and try it out for yourself. One of it can be found on this link

http://willowtreeapps.com/blog/wwdc-2016-rich-notifications-in-ios-10/